# Converting a "Kind-less" DateTime to universal time while specifying culture and source timezone

Tags: c#, datetime

I am tripping over myself here with figuring out how to standardize times coming into our system. We are in an unfortunate situation where our API is being fed a **stringified** time like this

`2/3/20,08:47:28`

I know for a fact that the times being fed are in user's local times. I am also getting a timezone along with the api call such as **"Eastern Standard Time"**

From my understanding on reading the following [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/converting-between-time-zones) I cannot convert to UTC unless the date string itself has offset info (which it does not)

Using the same article I have tried to get to UTC with the following test scenario in a linqpad.

```
var str = "2/3/20,08:47:28";
var date = DateTime.Parse(str, new CultureInfo("en-Us"), DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal); 
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(date, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time")).Dump();
```

This doesn't seem to work because I think the `DateTime.Parse` is getting it's timezone info from my local machine and when I try to convert it to an example **Eastern Standard Time** it blows because that is not the timezone I am in.

**My question is**
**Is there a way to parse a date from a string without the DateTime structure assuming the local computer's timezone?**

Comment: "*I am also getting a timezone along with the api call*" - what sort of data is this, an offset, name, abbreviation, ect ?

Comment: I will update the question but as an example I am getting "Eastern Standard Time"

Comment: Given your example, what do you expect the datetime to be?

Comment: It should be `2/3/20 01:47:28` as that would be the UTC time for NY at 8:47AM NY time

Comment: Maybe you can add the time zone offset to the input string before converting to DateTime/DateTimeOffset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand the problem, this may work for you `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

<sub>*Fair warning, date and times aren't my forte*</sub>

```
var parsed = DateTime.Parse("2/3/20,08:47:28", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-EU"));
var Id = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
var result = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(parsed, Id, TimeZoneInfo.Local);
Console.WriteLine(result.ToUniversalTime());
```

**Output**

```
2/3/2020 1:47:28 PM
```

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/s6kc5T)

Comment: Looks like that works. Date times are not my forte either, they give me headaches.